# Dynamic Checkbox in GridView

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want a CheckBox in my GridView which should be already checked if `IsApproved` is `true` in database and the `ForeColor` should change accordingly. If we uncheck the box then `IsApproved` should become `false`. This piece of code is not working . Can someone provide a better solution ?

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Status"
                   ItemStyle-CssClass="text-center"
                   HeaderStyle-CssClass="text-center">
  <ItemTemplate>
    <asp:CheckBox ID="lblmajor"
                  runat="server"
                  Checked='<%# (bool)Eval("IsApproved")==true?true:false %>'
                  ForeColor='<%# (bool)Eval("IsApproved")==true?System.Drawing.Color.Green:System.Drawing.Color.Red %>'>
    </asp:CheckBox>
  </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

Comment: So, What's your problem?

Comment: Please clarify what your actual issue is here.  Is there an issue or do you simply which to improve on that code?  Please revise your question to allow us to properly help you with a clear statement of the issue you face. https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0):

Here, `IsApproved` is `boolean` field right?
If yes then you don't need to use conditional operator.

Simply use this way :

```
 Checked='<%# Eval("IsApproved") %>'
 ForeColor='<%#iif(Eval("IsApproved"),"Green","Red") %>'
```

Comment: While this is an improvement, I do not feel the OP has really stated what the actual problem is yet.

Comment: ForeColor statement is not correct. It is throwing error.